# Associate CDRom device with drive letter

Tags: windows, winapi, wmic, cd-rom

I am writing a program that makes disk images of a CD-ROM drive. I need to create a full disk image, not just a volume image, but I need a volume name so I can name the resulting file accordingly.

Basically I need this:

[image]

I know that my CD-ROM drive is CD-ROM 0, and I need to know which volumes are there.

I tried to query WMI from PowerShell, but no luck.

`Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk` gives me all drive letters and volume labels.

`Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskPartition` gives me a list of partitions without any labels/letters.

`Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_PhysicalMedia` is gives me a device address (?) like `\\.\CDROM0`.

`Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_DiskDrivePhysicalMedia` is useless, it just has hard drives in it, no CD-ROMs.

What am I missing?

I want a way to see that `\\.\CDROM0` has a volume with letter D and whatever label. Is there a way to do this? Maybe some kernel32 functions?

Answer (score 0):

The [Win32_LogicalDisk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-logicaldisk) WMI class has a property `VolumeName` that gives you the name of the inserted disk (if it has any). That corresponds with what you have highlighted in your screenshot.

Comment: But what if I have more than one CD-ROM in the system? How can I match `\\.\CdromX` with drive letters?

Answer (score 0):

According to some previous information, the device names of multiple CD-ROMs may be changed after reboot(I didn't test them).

Link:[First CD-ROM device: CdRom0 or CdRom1?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.nt.kernel-mode/eoL1j6TPAJM)

So I recommend matching drive letters with CD-ROM GUID.

1. Get the GUID of each CD-ROM through `GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint`

   GUID such as: VolumeName: \?\Volume{f3b89248-8457-1ae3-9f8c-806e6f6b6923}\

   From here you can use a substring or regex to cut out the part that contains the GUID.
2. Get the drive letter of CD-ROM through `GetLogicalDrives` and `GetDriveType`.
3. Get the GUIDs of each CD-ROM drive letter obtained in Step 2,Compare the GUIDs with the GUID from `GetVolumeNameforVolumeMountPoint` in Step 1, and the two GUIDs match successfully if they are the same.